# Verifying an open cover

Tags: real-analysis

I have stumbled upon the following question:

*Check if the family $$ \zeta=\left\{\left(r_{n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},r_{n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $$ is an open cover of $ \mathbb{R} $, where $ (r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a linear array of all rational numbers.*

I confess that I do not know the meaning of "linear array of all rational numbers". I presume that $ (r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence of all rational numbers. But I could not proceed with the formal proof. Intuitively I can visualise that this will cover the entire real line, but cannot proceed with any solid argument. Any hint is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The lengths of those intervals sum to $1.$ How could they cover the whole real line?

Comment: A "Linear Array" is just a list/sequence/numbering of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @zhw., Ah! thanks. I was thinking, as the rationals are dense, the intervals are spread over entire $\mathbb{R}$, and will capture every real number. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Let $|J$| denote the length of an interval $J$.  A basic step in the development of Lebesgue measure is that if $K$is an interval and if a finite or infinite family $C$ of open intervals is a cover of $K$ then $\sum_{J\in C}|J|\ge |K|.$ So the family in your Q does not cover $any$ interval $J$ such that $|J|>1$.